# c++ can not get value from map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have implemented a serializer to send data over network. And I have implemented a system that can deserialize primitive data, string, map(string, string), map(string, float), but the error happens with map(string, int) when the deserialized map is used to fetch the value from key. In the debugger I can see that map receive correct value but when I'm trying to get data, I get an error "std::out_of_range at memory location".

Here is my code

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

#define STREAM_ENDIANNESS 0
#define PLATFORM_ENDIANNESS 0

using namespace std;

class OutputMemoryStream
{
void ReallocBuffer(uint32_t inNewLength)
{
    mBuffer = static_cast<char*>(std::realloc(mBuffer, inNewLength));
    mCapacity = inNewLength;
}

char*       mBuffer = nullptr;
uint32_t    mHead;
uint32_t    mCapacity;
public:
OutputMemoryStream() : mHead(0) { ReallocBuffer(32); }

~OutputMemoryStream()
{
    if (mBuffer) { mBuffer = nullptr; }
}

char*       GetBufferPtr()  const { return mBuffer; }
uint32_t    GetLength()     const { return mHead; }

void        Write(const void* inData, size_t inByteCount)
{
    //make sure we have space...
    uint32_t resultHead = mHead + static_cast<uint32_t>(inByteCount);
    if (resultHead > mCapacity)
    {
        ReallocBuffer(std::max(mCapacity * 2, resultHead));
    }

    //copy into buffer at head
    std::memcpy(mBuffer + mHead, inData, inByteCount);

    //increment head for next write
    mHead = resultHead;
}

template< typename T > void Write(T inData)
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic< T >::value || std::is_enum< T >::value, "Generic Write only supports primitive data types");

    if (STREAM_ENDIANNESS == PLATFORM_ENDIANNESS)
    {
        Write(&inData, sizeof(inData));
    }
    else {  }
}

template< typename T >
void Write(const std::map< string, T >& inMap)
{
    uint32_t elementCount = inMap.size();
    Write(elementCount);
    for (std::pair<string, T> element : inMap)
    {
        Write(element.first);
        Write(element.second);
    }
}

void Write(const std::string& inString)
{
    size_t elementCount = inString.size();
    Write(elementCount + 1);
    Write(inString.data(), (elementCount + 1) * sizeof(char));
}
};

class InputMemoryStream
{
private:
char*       mBuffer;
uint32_t    mHead;
uint32_t    mCapacity;

public:
InputMemoryStream() {}
InputMemoryStream(char* inBuffer, uint32_t inByteCount) : mBuffer(inBuffer), mCapacity(inByteCount), mHead(0) { }

~InputMemoryStream()
{
    if (mBuffer) { mBuffer = nullptr; }
}

uint32_t        GetRemainingDataSize() const 
{
    return mCapacity - mHead;
}

void Read(void* outData, uint32_t inByteCount)
{
    uint32_t resultHead = mHead + inByteCount;
    if (resultHead > mCapacity)
    {
        //handle error, no data to read!
        //...
    }

    std::memcpy(outData, mBuffer + mHead, inByteCount);

    mHead = resultHead;
}


template< typename T > void Read(T& outData)
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic< T >::value || std::is_enum< T >::value, "Generic Read only supports primitive data types");
    Read(&outData, sizeof(outData));
}

template<typename T1>
void Read(std::map<string, T1> &mapP)
{
    size_t elemenCount;
    Read(elemenCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < elemenCount; i++)
    {
        string key; T1 value;
        Read(key);
        Read(value);
        std::pair<string, T1> pair(key, value);
        mapP.insert(pair);
    }
}

void Read(string &outString)
{
    size_t strSize;
    Read(strSize);
    outString.resize(strSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < strSize; i++)
    {
        Read(&outString[i], 1);
    }
}
};

class ServerObject
{
OutputMemoryStream outStream;
InputMemoryStream inStream;
map<std::string, int> mapInt;
public:
ServerObject() {};
ServerObject(char* byteArray, int byteCount)
{
    InputMemoryStream inStream(byteArray, byteCount);
    Deserialize(inStream);
}
~ServerObject() {};

void Serialize()
{
    outStream.Write(mapInt);
}

void Deserialize(InputMemoryStream inStream)
{
    inStream.Read(mapInt);
}

OutputMemoryStream GetOutStream()
{
    return outStream;
}

int GetInt(string key)
{
    return mapInt.at(key);
}

void PutInt(string key, int value)
{
    mapInt.insert(std::pair<string, int>(key, value));
}
};

int main()
{
ServerObject * so = new ServerObject();
so->PutInt("test", 10);
so->Serialize();
ServerObject * so1 = new ServerObject(so->GetOutStream().GetBufferPtr(), so->GetOutStream().GetLength());
int i = so1->GetInt("test");
system("pause>NULL");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not with the detail provided, no. Please present your [mcve].

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question. Please post code not images

Comment: " can see value is correct but I can not use that value. " what does that mean? How is it possible to "see" the value without "using" it?

Comment: I send "testInt" and 100. after receiving it on client. mapP does has key:"testInt" and value: 100 but when it call mapP.at("testInt") the error happen

Comment: My bet is that the two keys are not actually the same.

Comment: Most likely, `key` contains something that is invisible in the debugger view - or it is invalid - so it is not exactly `"testInt"`. Check your `Read` function.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode - seriously, it is _easier_ to copy & paste code into a text box than it is to insert screenshots.

Comment: `testlnt` looks exactly the same as `testInt` in the debugger font: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYpwz.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7fWP.png

Comment: http://codepad.org/3wsx3TpB. I have minimized the code and put it in the link, that code can reproduce my problem.

Comment: @Lirus "_I have minimized the code and put it in the link_" The entire [mcve] must be in the question itself, and not in external links.

Comment: I tried to compile your code, but my IDE doesn't accept images or pictures. :-(

Comment: @Lirus `size_t` has 8 bytes, `uint32_t` has 4 bytes. Now look at writing/reading `map` functions, do you see it? Change one type to be like the other. Second issue, while writing `string` remove `+1`, you don't reserve memory for null terminator. Should work.

Comment: I have edited my post with the minimal code inside the post. Thanks you guys for coming here to give me advice so that I can make a better post next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `void Write(const std::string& inString)` function of `OutputMemoryStream` should not store additional byte of buffer for null terminator because `std::string` will not contain null terminator but if you use `c_str()`, a null terminator will be included in the return from this method. Don't get confused with the internal structure of the memory. `std::string` stores the length of the string in its member variable so there is no need of null terminator. The function should be as shown below.

```
void Write(const std::string& inString)
{
    size_t elementCount = inString.size();
    Write(elementCount);
    Write(inString.data(), elementCount * sizeof(char));
}
```

Comment: That works, but why this error didn't happen with map(string, float) ?

Comment: @Lirus It should happen for any types. But to check and explain to you, you have not posted the code for float type. If you think above answer has answered the question you had asked, accept it as answer. This would also help others to focus on unanswered questions.